# how to use traversable on a tree

Tags: haskell, tree-traversal

I'm trying to understand how I can use Traversable to iterate over my tree data structure.
I've got this ugly tree (forest actually) that looks like this:

```
data ParseTree a = Leaf a | Node a (ParseTree a) (ParseTree a) | MultiNode a [ParseTree a]
       deriving (Show, Functor, F.Foldable, T.Traversable)

t = Node S 
(Node NP (Leaf DP) (Leaf NP)) 
(MultiNode VP 
[Node VP (Node VP (Leaf VP) (Leaf PP)) (Node NP (Leaf DP) (Leaf NP)),
Node VP (Leaf VP) (Node PP (Leaf PP) (Node NP (Leaf DP) (Leaf NP)))]
)
```

I want to find the multinodes so I can replace build new trees, one for each item in the multinode.

its easy enough for me to write a function like this

```
findmulti :: ParseTree a -> [ParseTree a]
findmulti (Leaf a) = []
findmulti (Node a left right) = findmulti left ++ findmulti right
findmulti (MultiNode a lst) = [ (MultiNode a lst) ]
```

But I think I should be able to use traverse to go down the list and find the items for me.
if I do

```
traverse print t
```

I get only the values at the very end:

S
NP
DP
NP
VP
VP
VP
VP
PP...

But I actually want the traversal to stop at the Multinodes. How do I control the depth of the traversal? Or is that not possible because Traversable and friends are agnostic as to the container?

Eventually I want to derive lenses that will allow me to replace the multinodes too, but right now I'm just trying to get a grasp on how traversable works. Am I even using the right tool for the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly easy to build a `Traversal'` which visits whatever you like, though this capability is much more general than what `Data.Traversable` allows as *that* `Traversal` must visit only and exactly the contained elements.

To begin, let's examine the signature of `traverse`

```
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

I like to call the first argument the "injection" function. Anything that is injected into the `Applicative`, `f`, is "visited" by the `Traversal`. In this case, we'd like to visit the `MultiNode`s so we can specialize this type already.

```
multinodes :: Applicative f => (ParseTree a -> f (ParseTree a)) -> ParseTree a -> (f (ParseTree a))
```

Or

```
multinodes :: Traversal' (ParseTree a) (ParseTree a)
```

Now let's consider the definition. Again, the goal is to inject each `MultiNode`.

```
-- No multinodes here, so we use `pure` so as to inject nothing at all
multinodes inj l@Leaf{} = pure l

-- Here's a multinode, so we'll visit it with the injection function
multinodes inj m@Multinode{} = inj m

-- And we need to neither reject (thus stopping the traversal)
-- nor inject a branch. Instead, we continue the traversal deeper
multinodes inj (Node a l r) = 
  (\l' r' -> Node a l' r') <$> multinodes inj l
                             <*> multinodes inj r
```

This is our `Traversal'`.

```
>>> t ^.. multinodes
[MultiNode VP [Node VP (Node VP (Leaf VP) (Leaf PP)) (Node NP (Leaf DP) (Leaf NP)),Node VP (Leaf VP) (Node PP (Leaf PP) (Node NP (Leaf DP) (Leaf NP)))]]
```

---

This code isn't much shorter than the code written for `findmulti`---in fact, it's nothing more than an unfolded `findMulti . traverse`, but it's immediately compatible with other `lens` combinators and demonstrates the general method of feeding an `Applicative` through a type while targeting the desired inner structures. Writing this `Traversal'` just once will be a general tool for almost any kind of visitation upon the `MultiNode`s.

Comment: I really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction. With a couple includes and translating "Branch" to "Node" I'm off and running with lenses. I can tell awesomeness will follow!

Comment: Ah, whoops! I retyped it to check the code and apparently missed that :) But +1 for the power of Traversals—good luck! (Fixed the typo now for future viewers)

Comment: To perhaps impose on you a bit further, I now see that your "multinodes" function is almost like an applicative version of fmap specialized to my ParseTree type. This goes a long way toward explaining why it works. To go a step further, how do I use this as a setter? It looks like "^.." works as a getter, and "^." is a settter? Still I can't seem to make that work.

Comment: "t ^. multinodes (Leaf VP)" was what I expected. to do the trick

Comment: Briefly, `(.~)` is for setting (but note that it takes 3 arguments, so its use is a little different from `(^.)`). For more details, [I wrote up a quick primer to Lenses on FP Complete.](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) This document is a little whirlwindy but gets through the use of lenses, prisms, and traversals (which `(^..)` is useful for).